# Getting at template parameter types of a template type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a question about templates and it is in the code:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  T t;
};

template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  T t; //<- how to get T here (preferably without using typedef in foo)
};
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean, "how do I get `T` when `FooType` is a `foo<T>`?"?

Comment: I pity the fool who is trying to get 'T' here.

Comment: @user93353 +1 Yeah, try to get T and you'll get Foo instead.

Comment: @user93353 can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use template specialization as follows. Given your `foo<>` class template:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  T t;
};
```

Define a `bar<>` primary template and a corresponding specialization this way:

```
template<typename FooType>
struct bar;

template<typename T>
struct bar<foo<T>> {
  T t; // T will be int if the template argument is foo<int>
};
```

Under the assumption that you are always supposed to instantiate `bar` by providing an instance of `foo<>` as the type argument, you can leave the primary template undefined.

The specialization will match the `foo<T>` pattern, thus giving you the type with which `foo<>` is instantiated in `T`.

Here is how you could test the validity of this approach with a simple program:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    bar<foo<int>> b;

    // This will not fire, proving T was correctly deduced to be int
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(b.t), int>::value, "!");
}
```

Here is the corresponding [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0c4fe23b3ea73e1a69889d6d058a315c-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a generic template argument type extractor:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename> struct tuplify;

template <template <typename...> class Tpl, typename ...Args>
struct tuplify<Tpl<Args...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
using get_template_argument
    = typename std::tuple_element<N, typename tuplify<T>::type>::type;
```

Usage:

```
get_template_argument<std::vector<int>, 1> a;  // is a std::allocator<int>
```

Or in your case:

```
get_template_argument<FooType, 0> t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want or can't add a typedef to `foo`, you can additionally write an independent "extractor" template

```
template <typename T> struct ExtractT;
template <typename T> struct ExtractT<foo<T> > {
  typedef T type;
};
```

and use it as

```
template<typename FooType>
struct bar {
  typename ExtractT<FooType>::type t;
};
```

You can take that `ExtractT` one step further and decouple it from `foo`

```
template <typename T> struct ExtractT;
template <template <typename> class C, typename T> struct ExtractT<C<T> > {
  typedef T type;
};
```

and so on until you reinvent something from Boost or C++11 standard library :) BTW, this feels like something that should already be available in form of a more generic solution....

Comment: I sense a `TemplateArgument<foo, N>` trait coming up :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Once could write a trivial trait to get a `tuple<...>` out of an `X<...>`, and then use `tuple_element<>` to extract the types... just thinking aloud though, may not make sense

Comment: @AndyProwl: Pff, reusing standard components, [how lame](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f67ec8d8d4ac23afbab140181bddb1fd-29e182f7ca6e65f5df784fe9d3b6118a). :P

Comment: @Xeo: Stop outsmarting me :-P